# A simple error while running a python script

Tags: python, linux, virtual-machine

I am trying to run backup.py of the python script which is in this link  .https://github.com/wefixit-AT/oVirtBackup/blob/master/backup.py

It is throwing me this error as ..

```
2019-08-13 01:47:03,583: Start backup for: 36650
2019-08-13 01:47:03,829: Snapshot creation started ...
2019-08-13 01:47:03,829: Snapshot created
2019-08-13 01:47:14,042: !!! No snapshot found !!!
2019-08-13 01:47:14,042: All backups done
2019-08-13 01:47:14,042: Backup failured for:
2019-08-13 01:47:14,042: 36650
2019-08-13 01:47:14,042: Some errors occured during the backup, please check the log file
```

I couldnt identify what is the problem with this.I am using oVirt Engine Version: 4.1.5.2-1.el7.centos

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
if vms_with_failures:
        logger.info("Backup failured for:")
        for i in vms_with_failures:
            logger.info("  %s", i)

    if has_errors:
        logger.info("Some errors occured during the backup, please check the log file")
        api.disconnect()
        sys.exit(1)
```

Check your log file pls. Can't help without log file.

Comment: thanks for your help.But one doubt
do you mean the log file of oVirt Engine or the log file of the backup.py script